# How to migrate empty strings from DB2 to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, db2, bcp

I'm going to export DB2 data to CSV file and want to use it with bcp command to import to SQL Server

I have a problem with empty string migration.In bcp, an empty character is a control code of 0x00, so when exporting on the DB2 side I'm trying to output a file with empty characters as 0x00:

```
export to /tmp/output5.csv of DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL
select 
CASE WHEN COL2 = '' THEN BINARY('',1) ELSE COL2 END AS COL2,
CASE WHEN COL3 = '' THEN BINARY('',1) ELSE COL3 END AS COL3
from TBL1
;
```

I got SQL Error:

> SQL0581N  The data types of the result-expressions of a CASE expression or
> DECODE function are not compatible.  SQLSTATE=42804

How to output a control code to a file when the data is an empty string?

Comment: cast(binary('', 1) AS VARCHAR(1)) perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Thank you for answer.

I got an another error.
SQL0461N  A value with data type "SYSIBM.BINARY" cannot be CAST to type
"SYSIBM.VARCHAR".  SQLSTATE=42846

Answer (score 1):

Using x'00' instead of BINARY('',1) seems to work fine.

```
export to /tmp/output.csv of DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL
select 
CASE WHEN COL2 = '' THEN x'00' ELSE COL2 END AS COL2,
CASE WHEN COL3 = '' THEN x'00' ELSE COL3 END AS COL3
from TBL1
```